# What are all the ways to increase Friendship in Pokemon X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm looking for all the ways to increase Friendship in Pokemon X and Y.  Note that Friendship is different from Pokemon Amie Affection; they both do different things.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Boosts Happiness**

- Walking 128 steps
- Getting a massage (Cyllage City)
- Using vitamins
- Levelling up
- Using EV berries
- Soothe Bell (Shalour City)

**Reduces happiness**

- Fainting
- Using bitter medicine

Trading resets a Pokémon to its base happiness

[Here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Happiness) is the happiness page from Bulbapedia. It has not yet been updated for XY, but the boosts from Gen V have not altered.

Comment: Hmm, mobile SE doesn't seem to recognise line breaks or list syntax from my phone for some reason. If anyone could edit and reformat this, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: There is also a happiness punching bag that can be obtained from super training.

Comment: I thought you had to walk 256 steps to get 1 point of friendship?

Answer (score 2):

You can usually get a Pokémon to have it's friendship raised in many ways really. Like, if you give your Pokémon vitamins like protein, carbos, etc.. You can also raise it's friendship by letting it hold a soothe bell, walking around with it or just plain battling with it! Then if you level it up it might evolve! But beware! PokemonAmie does not raise your friendship, but it does raise chances of critical hits, evasion, and status moves such as endure. And stay away from letting it faint and feeding it herbs, hope I helped!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the Befriending O-Power with soothe bell on your pokemon then ride around the prism tower in lumoise city to gain friendship fast

Answer (score 1):

According to my guide

1. Pokemon Amie
2. Travelling together
3. Leveling up
4. Use stat-boosting items
5. Use items during battle (things like: X Accuracy, X Attack)
6. Use a TM or HM
7. Battling gym leaders
8. Hold a soothe bell
9. Get a massage in Cyllage City
10. Use the befriending O-Power

Answer (score 0):

Friendship is increased like it has been in previous generations: winning battles with your Pokemon, using items such as Potions on it, and just moving around with it in your party. Note you can lower happiness if the Pokemon faints or you use herbal medicines on it. Pokemon-Amie is rumored to increase happiness in small amounts, but this is not confirmed.

Comment: According to [this discussion on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67478775) and [this discussion on Marriland](http://www.marriland.com/forums/pokemon-6th-generation/pokemon-x-y/448295-pokemon-amie-questions) Amie increases "affection", not happiness, which are two mutually exclusive stats. Affection yields positive effects in battle, such as increasing the critical hit rate.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I have found is the pink punching bags you get from super training.